# Finding the height and base of an isosceles triangle whose equal sides are given.

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let the given side be $5$;

My approach to solving this is:

let $\phi$ be the angle formed by the side and height of the triangle, and $θ$ be the angle between the base and side.

then,

$$2θ + 2\phi = 180$$

or,

$$ \sin^{−1}(h/5) +  \sin^{−1}\Big(\frac{b/2}{h}\Big) =  \sin^{−1}(1)$$

or,

$$h/5 + b/2h = 1 $$

or,

$$2h^2 + 5b = 10h     \hspace{1cm}        \text{---- eqn (1)}$$

Using Pythagorean theorem:

$$h^2 + (b/2)^2 = 5^2     \hspace{1cm}   \text{---- eqn (2)}$$

Now, solving these two equations and getting `h` and `b` doesn't seem good. So how should I find out the $h$ and $b$ when I am given with one side of the isosceles triangle?

Comment: No angles given?

Comment: @XcoderX nope...

Comment: The angle between the 2 equal sides is not determined, it is unsolvable

Comment: $\sin^{-1}(90)=1$?? What's that?

Comment: We have to address the problem.  It provides insufficient info

Comment: @velutluna i think he means sin90

Comment: $\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y=\sin^{-1}z$ implies $x + y = z$??

Comment: Yes, that's a mistake, I left mathematics 4 years ago, so... BTW there has to be something using which this can be solved.

Comment: I don't think you can. There are infinitely many isosceles triangles with a given side length.

Comment: @velutluna yes, you are right. But for a given side can we determine if the base length is odd or even? or the height if a perfect integer (no floating)? Perhaps, this isn't apt. to ask you here in comment, but still if you can help.

Comment: The base can be any value between 0 and 10.  The height will always be $\sqrt {25- \frac {b^2}4} $ which can be any value between 0 and 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't solve it based only on the side given. The problem is missing information.

If the side is $c$, pick any length $a$, $0\lt a\lt 2c$ - and you can construct an isosceles triangle with base $a$ and side $c$.

Once the base is fixed, the triangle is uniquely determined up to congruency, and the height corresponding to the base is $h=\sqrt{c^2-\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2}$

Answer (score 0):

Having a side of an isosceles triangle is not sufficient to construct such a triangle. The base length could be any number greater than zero and less than twice the length of the given side.